# When was the electronvolt first introduced?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, units

When was the unit "electronvolt" (eV) first introduced, and by whom?

The definition of the eV requires the knowledge of the electron charge $e$, so it must have been introduced after 1909, the date of the famous [oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) conducted by R. A. Millikan and H. Fletcher, in which, as far as I know, $e$ was measured for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

The *OED*'s "[electronvolt](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/270197)" entry gives this as the earliest usage in English:

- [1925 *Proc. Royal Soc.* A. **109** 559](https://www.jstor.org/stable/94475?seq=20)

  > Now one electron-volt = 1·59 .10<sup>−12</sup> ergs, and 4·18 .10<sup>−17</sup> ergs = 1 gram-calorie.

[image: ibid., p. 549]

But it defines what its measure is, not what it is.